Constant time AND operator in Dafny?
I'm working on a demonstration of a Dafny proof that an operation takes constant time, or at least a fairly constant number of machine cycles. It's the kind of thing you need when you're trying to prevent side-channel-attacks. Here's what I have so far:
method IndexOf( s: seq<int>, value: int) returns (index: int)
    // Answers the index of value in s:
    requires value in s
    ensures 0 <= index < |s|
    ensures s[index] == value
    ensures value !in s[0..index]
{
    ghost var numIterations := 0;
    ghost var numFirstBranch := 0;

    var result := -1;
    for i := 0 to |s|
        invariant result == -1 ==> value !in s[0..i]
        invariant result < |s|
        invariant result >= 0 ==> value !in s[0..result]
        invariant result >= 0 ==> s[result] == value
        invariant numIterations == i
        invariant result != -1 ==> numFirstBranch==1
        invariant result == -1 ==> numFirstBranch==0
        { numIterations := numIterations + 1;
            if (s[i] == value) && (result == -1) 
            { numFirstBranch := numFirstBranch + 1;
                result := i;
            }
        }
    assert numIterations == |s|;
    assert numFirstBranch == 1;
    return result;
}

Sorry about the huge number of loop invariants - they're all necessary. But this does satisfies the timing constraints - for a given length of sequence s, the number of executions of each different path is constant.
Alas, though, that's not correct, because the test (s[i] == value) && (result == -1) actually involves two different execution paths, since the RHS will not be evaluated if the LHS is false.
The classic solution, replacing && with &, doesn't work - Dafny won't accept & between two booleans (why???). Casting the booleans to integers isn't allowed either.
I'm stuck. How can I test two expressions together without involving multiple execution paths?

I am not sure if the semantics of C can be exactly replicated in Dafny. I think you will need to abstract away operations which are atomic in C as functions or methods in Dafny. Although the operations in Dafny may not be be atomic you can abstract them away and define a count on them which represents the behavior in C.
Here is an example that you might find helpful. https://dafny.org/blog/2023/10/11/insertion-sort/

The way to think about it is not to recreate the exact same code but to establish the relationships are the same and maintained with invariants/postconditions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oshxAJGrwMU

Are you trying to implement a Dafny code equivalent to the C code you already have?

It's a bit unclear what your question is. Single & is only allowed for bit vectors in Dafny.
Here is an example of how you could cast a boolean to a bit vector of size 8 and 1 respectively. Use a bv1 if it is literally just for booleans. Large bit vectors are very slow to verify.
var test := true;
var foo: bv8 := if test then 1 else 0;
var bar: bv1 := if test then 1 else 0;
var baz := (if test then 1  else 0) as bv16;

function toBv1(x: bool): bv1 {
  if x then 1 else 0
}


The aim of the OP is to get a method where every path through the method is counted (and  the number of executions is independent of values in the input data). The code
if x then 1 else 0
adds two further paths, so this approach won't solve the problem.

To be more clear, whether Dafny semantics matches C semantics is irrelevant. They don't, and it doesn't matter. What you can do in Dafny in model the semantics of C and prove things about that model.

OK - so you're saying Dafny's generated code isn't going to work. We'll have to add a manual step taking the Dafny code and transliterating it to C. That's a bit of a blow, when the major selling point of Dafny is its generation of code that can be integrated as is with other parts of a system.

Dafny's main use case and major selling point is verifying properties about your program are true AFAIK. The compilation is useful to test the logic and compare against other programs but I am not sure that it is guaranteeing generated code is production ready or if it even provides controls about how it is compiled down like you might need for a security sensitive application. Rustan Leino (language creator) and others more knowledgable might comment on this later.
